# Line-preserving transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Is there a name for the class of transformations on the Euclidean plane (or projective plane) that preserves lines?

They are not all affine transformations; consider a perspective projection $p$ in 3D Euclidean space (center of projection at $(1,1,0)$) from the $xz$-plane to the $yz$-plane. This map is not affine.

Could it be that all transformations on the plane that preserve lines are results of such projections?

Comment: http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gilbert/M333L/chp4vers4.pdf

Comment: @dato that article mentions only linear transformations (other than stereographic projection which I believe is irrelevant), but I am asking about transformations that preserve lines but are *not* linear, nor affine.

Answer (score 5):

A transformation of a projective plane which preserves lines is called a collineation. In every projective plane, a projective transformation will be a collineation. In the common Euclidean plane with the real numbers as the underlying field, the converse can be shown as well: every collineation is a projective transformation. If the underlying field has a non-trivial automorphism, the way the complex numbers do, this is no longer true. For example, one can compute the complex conjugate of every coordinate, thus preserving lines although that operation is not a projective transformation.

Source: Lectures by the author of [*Perspectives on Projective Geometry*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642172857).

Comment: Do you have links to the lectures slides? Do projective transformations form a group? Also, isn't the complex conjugate simply a reflection in the Euclidean plane, and would that "preserve lines although that operation [reflection] is not a projective transformation"?

Comment: @HerngYi: Slides are in German. Search for the [fundamental theorem of projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation#Fundamental_theorem_of_projective_geometry) for proofs in other languages. Projective transformation form the [projective general linear group PGL₂](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group). Conjugation is a reflection if you interpret ℂ (or ℂℙ¹) as a plane, but I was talking about ℂℙ². A reflection in ℝℙ² and ℂℙ² is a projective transformation.